# Time vs Top command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using command `time` to find how much time two commands are taking to execute one process (one after another). However, sometimes it gives:

```
command 1 elapsed time is 5:34.05
```

and

```
command 2 elapsed time is 6:32.98
```

But, in another window where `top` command is running, it shows,

```
command 1 TIME+ is 2:34.05

command 2 TIME+ is 2:14.09
```

Can anybody help me why is this happening means when time command says that command 1 takes less time at that same time top command says completely opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `top` command does not show elapsed time, but CPU usage time. The `time` command shows elapsed time and CPU time.

Comment: Sorry, if anything wrong. But, I have very little idea about those. Actually, I am trying to find how much wall clock time both two commands are taking to execute some operations and as I have suggested, I am using time command, but what output it is giving is hard to believe (!), because I am seeing both of them executes in just 1/2 minutes but time command gives they take 5/6 minutes ?

Comment: Are you running in a VMware guest?

Comment: I don't know. But, how to check that ?

Comment: I run this command:  lshw -class system
Outputs: WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall64 vsyscall32 [so probably NO]

Comment: And my time command also looks like: 105.99user 49.45system 5:34.05elapsed 48%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 32554768maxresident)k
55581424inputs+68080outputs (33major+9644074minor)pagefaults 0swaps. If it helps.